# accessing JSON array item from another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm a JS n00b, so my apologies for asking something so simple. (It's so simple that the rest of SO is providing more complex answers than I need.) I have a JSON array like this:

```
var comics = {"spider":"Spiderman", "bat":"Batman", "super":"Superman", "aqua":"Aquaman"};
```

And I want to access items in that array from another array, like so:

```
var childhood_heroes = {"fire":"Firefighters", "jordan":"Michael Jordan", "superhero":[comics.super, comics.bat]};
```

I'm attaching it with jQuery to a div in my HTML with:

```
$('#which_heroes').click(function() {
    $('#jobs').html(childhood_heroes.fire);
    $('#sports').html(childhood_heroes.jordan);
    $('#supers').html(childhood_heroes.superhero);
});
```

The first two work when the third is absent. The presence of the third breaks everything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a note, your JSON would be less coupled if `superheroes` were `["super", "bat"]`, instead of explicit references.

Comment: replace `[comics.super, comics.bat]` with `comics.super +' '+ comics.bat`

Comment: That is **not** a "JSON array". It is a JavaScript object.

Comment: Jason — I'm not sure what "less coupled" means, but I'll definitely look it up, thanks!

Val — I have this problem even if I only have one object in the array, so that probably isn't going to help. But thanks!

Felix — Um, thanks, but that still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @Heather: That is why I commented. If I wanted to solve your problem I would have provided an answer ;) Clarifying terminology is important too!

Comment: LOL, well, thanks! I'm always up for learning more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

`$('body').html(["one","two"]);`

Produces

`Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8`

So, your issue is that you're passing an array of strings to the jQuery `.html()` function, which apparently doesn't handle it too well. Turn it into a string before you pass it, something like

```
$('#supers').html(childhood_heroes.superhero.join(', '));
```

should work.

The two valid arguments for `.html()` from http://api.jquery.com/html/ are

```
html( htmlString  )
    .html( htmlString )
    .html( function(index, oldhtml) )
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I really appreciate the explanation for why what I was doing didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing an Array where you probably want a String, you can use join() to put all the entries in the superhero array into a string:

```
$('#supers').html(childhood_heroes.superhero.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `comics` is initialized before `childhood_heroes`.

And not to nitpick, but neither of the things you defined are JavaScript or JSON arrays.  They're only "arrays" in the very loose sense of ["associative arrays"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

Comment: I'm confused by your edit, are you saying JavaScript variables, Objects, Arrays, and jQuery code is not JavaScript?

Comment: You can also be precise and just say they are objects.

Comment: @Robert, I am saying that `{"spider":"Spiderman",...}` is not a JSON array as asserted in the OP.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the intent as being directed at the tags, saying that only Array was a warranted tag. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: My bad. Like I said, I'm just learning this. Associative arrays are all I've worked with. How does a "proper" array differ?

Comment: @Heather: "Proper arrays" in JavaScript have only numerical keys and are defined like `var arr = ['foo', 'bar'];`. Have a look at this JS guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: @Felix: Ahh, I see. Thanks for the link. I'll study that. I've used those arrays before; just didn't know the terminology. I'm still a bit fuzzy on how a JSON array is different from what I posted, though.

Comment: @Heather: JSON is a data exchange format. There is no other relation that JavaScript object literas and JSON objects have a *similar* syntax. Think about JSON like XML. Have a look at this: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 0):

The pair: `"super":"Superman"` will cause probs as `super` is reserved, so `comics.super` will raise an error in IE at least.

Rename it, or use `comics["super"]` notation.

Comment: Since my example is totally made up and has nothing to do with my actual code, I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. But thanks.